# MATLAB error when solving simultaneous equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am running a MATLAB code which solves a set of non-linear simultaneous equations. The code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqtgb6vxs4jhg2d/Solution.m?dl=0). The data input for the code (in excel) can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqie2ktcci9zyo1/CIMDO_BEL.xlsx?dl=0).

I encounter the following error:

```
Error using sym/subsasgn (line 733)
Indexed assignment to empty SYM objects is supported only in the 0-by-0 case.

Error in Solution (line 69)
    x(i,:) = (b(i,1) - b0)./(c(i,1)*x0) + c0/c(i,1);
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a symbolic variable, you have to specify the dimensions, otherwise it's a scalar. Instead of `syms x;` use `sym` and set the dimension argument:

```
x=sym('x',[3,4])
```

Replace [3,4] with the dimensions you want.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, where exactly do I insert that into my code?

Comment: Thanks, so I replaced it with `x=sym('x',[1,1])`, however I am still getting the same error. There is nothing wrong mathematically since it can be shown that there is always a solution to this set of equations.

Comment: x is definitely not of size [1,1] because you are indexing it using `x(i,:)`.